# How to populate Select control with ID value retrieved from JSON file using HTTPClient

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

In my Angular app, I am populating the below select control with values retrieved from a JSON file using HTTP Client.

```
<label for="manager">Manager:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="manager">
        <option value="" disabled>Choose manager</option>
        <option *ngFor="let manager of managers" [value]="manager.id">{{manager.fullName}}</option>
    </select>
```

Here is the `JSON`:

```
"managers": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "fullName": "Phil",
        "contactPreference": "email",
        "email": "phil@gmail.com",
        "phone": "0865963625"
    }
]
```

Here is where I am creating the form:

```
this.jobForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      managerId: [''],
    });
```

Here is a`job` object that I have:

```
job: IJob = {
    id: null,
    title: '',
    description: '',
    employeeId: null,
    managerId: null
  };
```

I want to populate the `managerId` of this `job` object with `manager.Id` from the select option

Here is my attempt, but it is not working:

```
this.job.managerId = this.jobForm.value.manager;
```

Can someone please tell me how I can access the ID from the select control & add it to my `job` object?

I also printed `console.log('MANAGER VALUE: ' + this.jobForm.value.manager);` but this is what is printed:

> MANAGER VALUE: undefined

Comment: You aren’t currently setting a value for the options generated from the ngFor. Either use [value] for a primitive value or [ngValue] for a complex value like an object.

Comment: how about you use ngModel instead

Comment: @paulws Hi, it's part of a reactive form. Are you able to use both?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thanks for your help, I've updated my code with `ngValue` and shown the error message I am getting

Comment: It doesn’t look like a reactive form. Where is formControlName directive or similar on the input? Please share how you are creating the form via form builder or similar.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky added

Comment: Okay so you need to tie the FormControl of the FormGroup to the input. This is usually done by using directive formControlName on the input that matches the FormControl identifier defined in the FormGroup. I’d recommend to take a step back and review the reactive forms tutorial because you are missing a few critical items right now.

Comment: This is what you need: `<select class="form-control" id="manager" formControlName="managerId">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I figured out what I needed to change.

I added `fomControlName` to the select control.

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" id="managerId" formControlName="managerId">
    <option value="" disabled>Choose manager</option>
    <option *ngFor="let manager of managers" [value]="manager.id">{{manager.fullName}}</option>
</select>
```

The formControlName above needs to match `managerId` in the FormBuilder below.

Typescript:

```
this.jobForm = this.fb.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      managerId: [''],
    });


this.job.managerId = this.jobForm.value.managerId;
```